# Получить словарь определенного вида

Tags: python, dataframe, словари, dict

Имеется датафрейм следующего вида:

```
q = [[nan, nan],
 [nan, nan],
 ['29', 'B'],
 ['29', 'D'],
 ['29', 'C'],
 [nan, nan],
 ['30', 'B'],
 ['30', 'D'],
 ['30', 'C'],
 [nan, nan],
 ['30', 'E'],
 ['30', 'G'],
 ['30', 'F'],
 [nan, nan],
 ['32', 'B'],
 ['32', 'D'],
 ['32', 'C'],
 [nan, nan],
 ['31', 'B'],
 ['31', 'D'],
 ['31', 'C']]
```

Названия колонок:

```
columns = ['source', 'own']
```

Требуется получить словарь следующего вида:

```
dict1 = {'29': ['B', 'D', 'C'],
 '30': ['B', 'D', 'C', '', 'E', 'G', 'F'],
 '32': ['B', 'D', 'C'],
 '31': ['B', 'D', 'C'],
 '33': ['B', 'D', 'C', '', 'E', 'G', 'F']}
```

На данный момент есть такое решение:

```
def get_correct_column_order(data_schema):
    correct_column_order = defaultdict(list)
    for i in range(data_schema.shape[0]):
        source = data_schema['source'].iloc[i]
        if isinstance(source, str):
            value = data_schema['own'].iloc[i]
            correct_column_order[source].append(value)
    return dict(correct_column_order)

df = pd.DataFrame(q, columns=columns)
get_correct_column_order(df)
```

и получаю словарь

```
dict2 = {'29': ['B', 'D', 'C'],
 '30': ['B', 'D', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'F'],
 '32': ['B', 'D', 'C'],
 '31': ['B', 'D', 'C'],
 '33': ['B', 'D', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'F']}
```

Comment: Как я понял, вы делитесь своими знаниями. Верно? Это хороший подход!

Comment: не совсем. dict1 отличается от dict2

Comment: Ладно, не угадал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем так сложно, обычный `groupby` работает. Но чтобы пустая строка ещё была, придётся сначала пошаманить:

```py
mask = df['source'].isnull() & (df['source'].ffill() == df['source'].bfill())
df.loc[mask, 'source'] = df['source'].ffill().loc[mask]
df.loc[mask, 'own'] = ''

df.groupby('source').agg(list)['own'].to_dict()
```

Вывод:

```
{'29': ['B', 'D', 'C'],
 '30': ['B', 'D', 'C', '', 'E', 'G', 'F'],
 '31': ['B', 'D', 'C'],
 '32': ['B', 'D', 'C']}
```

Если вы используете циклы в `Pandas`, значит вы что-то не то делаете, обычно всё можно решить "векторным" способом.

Comment: благодарю за подсказку. но мне нужно получить словарь немного другого вида - dict1

Comment: @ЕленаСергеева Ну, путём небольшого шаманства можно и так. Только я изменяю исходный датафрейм, если его нужно сохранить, то нужно сделать копию и работать с ней.